# Improving HTML5 canvas image loading

Tags: javascript, performance, html, canvas, load

So I'm creating a game and decided to use a canvas for the map. The map is big pictures 500kb+ (6400x6400px) and the canvas size is 320x320 so I am displaying only part of the image at a time and have the page reload on button click.

So first what I want to ask how can I stop the canvas from reloading the image on every page refresh when it only changes the displayed part not the image? Secondly how could I make the loading faster/more efficient? Can I make it only load the displayed part of the image? Any performance tips are welcomed, I can manipulate the image whatever way is needed.

Comment: Are you specifying width and height arguments in `drawImage`? E.g.: `ctx.drawImage('foo.png', 0, 0, 320, 320)` This should help with performance.

Comment: Yep, cxt.drawImage(img,0,0,320,320,0,0,320,320);

Answer (score 0):

1. Why to reload page? You can just redraw map.
2. You can cut big image to pieces, load and draw them on demand like Google Maps or any other modern cartographic service do.

Comment: 1. Because I need to display database updates. 2. That is an option, but I'm wondering is there another way.

Comment: Okay, that is the start of an answer... in its current form it only gives @Clueless the slightest of clues. Can you take it another step or two and give an example or point to some sample code on how to do what you suggest?

Comment: You can load them using AJAX without page relaod.

Comment: And there is no way to simply stop the image reloading with js (my skills at it suck)? And I prefer page reloading rather than using ajax. I'm looking for help not my methods of doing things questioned :(.